# Clarify this Javascript ternary

Tags: javascript, jscript, conditional-operator, ternary

Can someone split this nested ternary into multiple ternaries or other code or explain it in English? I've never come across a nested ternary like this so I'm not sure the order of operations:

```
var EqualizeCheck = (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) ? (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") ? (EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) ? true : false : false : true;
```

Comment: Break it down; put a line break after every `?` and every `:`, then have an IDE auto format it (or use the formatter here, using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: I imagine this goes without saying, but to anyone reading this, please don't write deeply-stacked ternary conditions if you have any other choice. (**Especially** when you are returning a boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work through it step by step, first separate the most nested condition (Look for a complete `condition ? value : value` statement) In this case that's this bit:

> var EqualizeCheck = (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) ? (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") ? **(EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) ? true : false** : false : true;

Separate that out and repeat for each ternary condition, until you have something like this:

```
// Condition 1:
(IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) ? 
    // Condition 1 == true, check the next condition
    // Condition 2: 
    (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") ? 
        // Condition 2 == true, check the next condition
        // Condition 3:
        (EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) ? 
            // Condition 3 == true, return true
            true :
            // Condition 3 == false, return false
            false :
        // Condition 2 == false, return false
        false :
    // Condition 1 == false, return true
    true;
```

Since this essentially boils down to two success conditions (Either where condition 1 is false, or where condition 2 and 3 are both true), you can vastly simplify it to this:

```
var EqualizeCheck = 
  !IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) ||
  ( 
    EqualizeCompleteTime != "" &&
    EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
let EqualizeCheck;

if (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) {
  if (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") {
    if (EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) {
      EqualizeCheck = true;
    } else {
      EqualizeCheck = false;
    }
  } else {
    EqualizeCheck = false;
  }
} else {
  EqualizeCheck = true;
}
```

I understand that it wasn't you who wrote this, but I should point out that nesting so many ternary expressions is a bad practice, and one that leads to unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

To get better idea just break it and try to apply `if-else` then you can understand easily. And also the thing mentioned by @Sagi Rika is correct, that nesting of many ternary expressions reduce the code readbilty which leads to difficult in understanding.

First lets break your ternary expressions as below:

```
var EqualizeCheck = (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON)
    ? (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") 
    ? (EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) 
    ? true 
    : false 
    : false 
    : true;
```

If you break it using `if-else` then it will be like as below:

```
var EqualizeCheck;

if (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) {
   if (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") {
      if (EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) {
         EqualizeCheck = true;
      } else {
         EqualizeCheck = false;
      }
   } else {
         EqualizeCheck = false;
   }
} else {
     EqualizeCheck = true;
}
```

To understand better let's take an example using `if-else`. Its like if the age is greater than than 18 then `canVote` will be `true` otherwise `canVote` will be `false`

```
var age = 19;
var canVote;

if (age > 18) {
   canVote = 'yes';
} else {
   canVote = 'no';
}
```

If we write the above code using ternary expressions then that will be like:

```
var age = 19;
var canVote = age > 18 ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the more readable friendly version of the above ternary oparator.

```
const EqualizeCheck = (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON) ? 
((EqualizeCompleteTime != "") ? ((EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) ? true : false) : false) : true;
```

If you divide that into a several ternary operator statements, it will looks as follows. I hope this format is easy to understand.

```
const EqualizeValueCheck = (IIO.ReadDigitalInput(IO_GROUP_CHARGERS, subGroupName, IO_ITEM_ENABLEEQUALIZE) == IO_INPUT_ON);
const EqualizeCompleteTimeCheck = (EqualizeCompleteTime <= CurrentDateTime) ? true : false;
const EqualizeCompleteTimeEmptyValueCheck = (EqualizeCompleteTime != "") ? EqualizeCompleteTimeCheck : false;
const EqualizeCheck = (EqualizeValueCheck) ? EqualizeCompleteTimeEmptyValueCheck : false;
```